# What values are truthy and falsey?

Tags: vimscript

What are the truthy and falsey values in classic vimscript (not vim9script)?

What is the canonical list, and where do I find it in `:help`?

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR:

**Truthy:**

- Non-`0` [Number](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#Number)s (any integer but `0`)
- Strings that convert to a non-zero number

  - All strings starting with a digit which is not `'0'`
  - Numbers not starting with `'0'`, eg:  `-123`  `0x10`  `0177`  `0o177`  `0b1011`

**Falsey:**

- `0` in integer form only -- float `0.0` gives `E805: Using a Float as a Number`
- `v:false`, `v:none` and `v:null`
- Any string that evaluates as `0` when `0` is added to it, eg: `'foo'`, `'0.9'`(**!**) and even `'+1'`(**!!!**)

**Error**:

- Anything that is not a [String](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#String) or a [Number](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#Number)

---

`:help Boolean` says:

> For boolean operators Numbers are used.  Zero is FALSE, non-zero is TRUE.
> You can also use `v:false` and `v:true`.

Note the emphasis on Numbers.  Strings can be converted to Numbers. Floats can't.

But that's not the complete story on the false side.

Neovim doesn't have a help index for `Specials`, but [vim's `:help Specials`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#Special) says:

> ```
> v:false, v:true, v:none and v:null.
> ```

These were introduced in Patch 7.4.1154.

Reading the help on these, we find that when used as Numbers, they respectively evaluate to:

```
      0,       1,      0,   and    0
```

To test if a string is truthy or not, add the Number `0` to it, eg:

```
:if '-1' + 0 | echo "true" | else | echo "false" | endif
```

The following strings all convert to the number `0` and are thus false:

- `'0'`
- `'0.9'`
- `''`
- `'non-number'`
- `'+1'` (!!!)

Note especially last one:

- `'-1'` converts to `-1` (truthy)
- `'+1'` converts to `0` (falsey)

Any string starting with a digit that is *not* `0` is true. '0.9' is false

[`:help Boolean`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#Boolean) says:

> If the string starts with a non-zero number it means TRUE

But note the following:

- Truthy: `'0xff'` and `'0777'` (Non-0 integers)
- Falsey: `0.9` (Float converts to integer `0`)

Comment: Great reference. v:true is relatively new, so many plugins still use 0/1, and the docs often say things in terms of 0/1. New code really should use v:true/v:false unless it absolutely needs the type-punning here

Comment: This actually gets even more confusing... Because Vim also uses a different concept of "truthy" and "falsy" (which it actually calls by these names) that is only used for the `??` operator. See [`:help truthy`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#truthy) and [`:help ??`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3F%3F).